# Glassfish - User [] from host 127.0.0.1 does not have administration access

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

Working with Glassfish, everything were ok, then I changed the password (box "Anonymous connection..." was checked) and set a password.

Now, password set, box "Anonymous connection" unchecked, application are still running fine BUT I'm spammed in Glassfish logs with a huge amount of

```
User [] from host 127.0.0.1 does not have administration access
User [] from host 127.0.0.1 does not have administration access
User [] from host 127.0.0.1 does not have administration access
...
```

and I get one line of this log every 2 seconds.

It looks like a service, or thread or whatever, trying to deal with my glassfish server, but I can't find what causes this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Try to start server without giving any user name and password.
T0 do this in Eclipse you can go to Server properties and under Glassfish empty the username and password field.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to leave the username and password fields empty when creating a new server in Eclipse. If the server was already created then deleting the username didn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I had resolved this issue at one point but it seems to have cropped back up again.  It does not appear to affect any other instance other than on my windows desktop. It has not precluded me from executing any functions (start, stop, deploys, admin console, etc. all work).

I did find a way to turn off the message as it was continuously filling up my logs. If you add the following entry to the logging.properties configuration file, it will turn these messages off.

javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.level=OFF

I will eventually go back and figure out why the error cropped up again, but I really have more important work to do right now other than researching this nuisance issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happened when the default Admin port `4848` has been already taken by some other application in your computer , so I have get rid of this problem by changing admin-listener port to some other port (in my case `5353`) This may solve your problem .

```
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml

network-listener port="5353" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"
```

I have resolved my same problem this way

Also try to make `eclipse > server >right click > properties > glassfish > put username pass as blank`

Answer (score 1):

WORKAROUND: edit C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\logging.properties and change

```
#javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.level=INFO
#This is a workaround so we do not see 
#User [] from host 127.0.0.1 does not have administration access `
javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.level=WARNING
```

Comment: Wait... Do you propose solving the problem where the user does not have administrative rights by not logging the message that tells it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't read the question carefully. In my case the lack of admin rights prevented even the deployment of the application, so it sounded like a non-solution. I just noticed that the original poster had no particular errors beside the annoying log messages, so in that case your workaround indeed makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans go to

```
Tools->Servers->user
```

and leave user and password as blank and start your server. Do that and its work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove and download again glassfish, I found only this solution

Answer (score 0):

In case of anyone get this problem again, I solved this deleting another glassfish configuration in my Eclipse.

A glassfish 4.0 configuration that I create, was influencing a glassfish 3.1 configuration that I had before.

The reason of this problem, I unfortunately don't know.

[]'s

Answer (score -1):

One solution that worked for me:-
Double click on glassfish server
Click on open server perspective page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rgIn.png)
Fill the username and pwd as admin and port as 4848